# How to get blender to open a specific internet browser

Tags: performance

I am using Waterfox as my browser. It is my default browser in my settings and all my file associations are set to Waterfox as my first choice. Despite this blender always opens internal internet links (such as the Manual) in Firefox. Is there a way to set a preferred internet browser within Blender.
Using Blender 2.93 LTS under Linux.
thanks

Comment: I don't think blender has a preference, I think you just haven't set the defaults right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172692/xdg-open-not-open-default-browser

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I needed to set some defaults through xdg-settings. Finally found how to do it and got it fixed. Thank you for answering.